# Why does Chandler tell the chick and the duck "back to Nintendo?"

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In *Friend* Season 3 Episode 22 there's the following scene:

> **Chandler:** [entering, carrying the chick and duck] *Hey! Can you take a duck and a chick to the theatre?*
>
> **Monica:** *Of course not.*
>
> **Phoebe:** *No.*
>
> **Chandler:** *Okay. I just wanted them to hear it from somebody else.* [to the chick and the duck] ***All, right, fellas, back to Nintendo.***

Is he saying that "***let's go back and play Nintendo***" or is he referring to the game in Nintendo where you kill ducks by a gun?

Comment: Very, very probably the former. Playing Nintendo is an alternative to going to see a film and the implication that he's playing Nintendo with the birds is funny enough. And as a joke, "Alright, instead of going to the movies, I'll to take you back to Duck Hunt where I got you from" makes much less sense.

Comment: I think hinting that ducks belong to Nintendo is pretty hilarious, but I guess it is only for me :)

Comment: Sure, it *could* be funny, but in *this context*, I think the other option makes more sense.

Answer (score 8):

My interpretation is that he was telling them that since they can't go to the theatre, they're going back to his room *to play Nintendo together* (e.g as a group). It's inherently funny to think of a grown man sitting in a room playing multi-player video games with two birds, not least because their stubby wings are almost uniquely unsuited for handling a controller.

Your alternate interpretation, that he was telling them to *go back to a Nintendo game* makes less sense, not least because there's no chicks or chicken in the most famous game of that genre, [Duck Hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Hunt)

Answer (score 3):

I think he is pretending to be a parent telling kids to go to their room and play nintendo coz they are not mature enough to go to a play.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, the reference to Nintendo could be the TV cabinet where the chick and the duck slept. Joey and Chandler had a PlayStation, and it is very much likely that they owned a Nintendo prior to owning a PS1. The Nintendo cabinet could have been where the guys put the chick and the duck to sleep.

Comment: Was this episode from before or after the PS1 though?

Comment: This was before the PS1 was shown. I am not sure, but the first time I remember seeing the PS1 is  definitely after season 5.